# Simple JSON array not working

Tags: javascript, php, json

This question should be easy to solve, but through trial and error and much google searching, I have no answer. I am trying to create a simple loop that will display the values from my JSON variable.

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<?php echo ($_SESSION['amort_JSON']); 
 
 ?>

 <script>
  
 var obj, i, j, x = 0;
 var obj = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['amort_JSON']) ?>); 
  
 for (i in obj.interest_paid) {
  x += obj[i].interest_paid;
 }

 //document.write(obj[8].interest_paid);
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
 
 </script>
```

`$_session['anirt_JSON']` returns the following value

```
[{
    "periodic_pmt": "2",
    "principle_balance": 416997.37661705,
    "principle_paid": 0,
    "ttl_principle_paid": 1002.6233829502,
    "interest_paid": 0,
    "ttl_interest_paid": 866.83015878773
}, {
    "periodic_pmt": 3,
    "principle_balance": 416600.29804453,
    "principle_paid": 538.02630958206,
    "ttl_principle_paid": 1540.6496925323,
    "interest_paid": 396.7004612869,
    "ttl_interest_paid": 1263.5306200746
}, {
    "periodic_pmt": 4,
    "principle_balance": 416203.59758324,
    "principle_paid": 538.40406076641,
    "ttl_principle_paid": 2079.0537532987,
    "interest_paid": 396.32271010256,
    "ttl_interest_paid": 1659.8533301772
}]
```

Thank you for your help. Learning is so much fun.

Comment: there is no array, and that is invalid JSON

Comment: Mine providing the parsed value in JavaScript rather than showing the `echo` from PHP? Assuming you have an array returned the value of `obj.interest_paid` wouldn't exist.

Comment: I am very new at learning all this great stuff. The blow script returns the right values .  <script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj[0].principle_balance + "<br> " + obj[3].principle_paid;
</script>

Comment: `for (i in obj.interest_paid)` should be `for (i in obj)` you hove to loop through the object. also note `obj.interest_paid` in not defined.

Comment: Remove the `JSON.parse()` from `JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['amort_JSON']) ?>);`. The output from `json_encode()` should already be valid JS, but if you want to treat it as JSON and parse it then you need to put quotes around it as `JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['amort_JSON']) ?>');`.

Comment: @nnnnnn nice catch. missed the quotes part. added that too to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access each item in the `obj` array by its index `i` (using `obj[i]`), you need to iterate over all possible index values for the array: `0` through `obj.length - 1`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
```

This instructs the JavaScript interpreter:

1. to start at `0`,
2. to stop before reaching `obj.length` (i.e., to end at `obj.length - 1`), and
3. to increment by `1` each time.

Answer (score 0):

Since the obj is an array of JSON objects, you can use the forEach loop to access every element.

```js
var obj = [{"periodic_pmt":"2","principle_balance":416997.37661705,"principle_paid":0,"ttl_principle_paid":1002.6233829502,"interest_paid":0,"ttl_interest_paid":866.83015878773},{"periodic_pmt":3,"principle_balance":416600.29804453,"principle_paid":538.02630958206,"ttl_principle_paid":1540.6496925323,"interest_paid":396.7004612869,"ttl_interest_paid":1263.5306200746}],
 x=0;

obj.forEach(function (element, index) {

    x += element.interest_paid;


});

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be

```
for (i in obj) {
    x += obj[i].interest_paid;
}
```

`obj` is the parsed json array and you should loop through it. `obj.interest_paid` does not exist as `obj` is an array of objects.

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wLprqyo3/)

***Edit:***

As @nnnnnn suggested you should have quotes around the string.

```
JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['amort_JSON']) ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing incorrect `JSON` Object. It should be `for (var i in obj) { ... }` instead of `for (var i in obj.interest_paid) { ... }`.

**Working Demo**

```js
var jsonObj = [{
    "periodic_pmt": "2",
    "principle_balance": 416997.37661705,
    "principle_paid": 0,
    "ttl_principle_paid": 1002.6233829502,
    "interest_paid": 0,
    "ttl_interest_paid": 866.83015878773
}, {
    "periodic_pmt": 3,
    "principle_balance": 416600.29804453,
    "principle_paid": 538.02630958206,
    "ttl_principle_paid": 1540.6496925323,
    "interest_paid": 396.7004612869,
    "ttl_interest_paid": 1263.5306200746
}, {
    "periodic_pmt": 4,
    "principle_balance": 416203.59758324,
    "principle_paid": 538.40406076641,
    "ttl_principle_paid": 2079.0537532987,
    "interest_paid": 396.32271010256,
    "ttl_interest_paid": 1659.8533301772
}];

var x = 0;
for (var i in jsonObj) {
  x += jsonObj[i].interest_paid;
 }
  
console.log(x);
```